# Select and open selected Finder window using keyboard

Tags: macos

Press CMD+TAB to see all applications opened.

Using left-right arrows select Finder.

Using up-down arrors open Finder windows selection.

Using arrows select (get blue border) Finder window.

And now how can I open selected finder window?

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the ENTER/RETURN key.

Tested locally on Yosemite 10.10.5. It may matter that I release the command key after up/down on Finder, before left/right selecting the window and hitting ENTER.

Comment: It does not work like that.
Once Enter is clicked MacOs displays the last application window displayed before CMD+Tab combination.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18568450)

Comment: @SzymonStepniak - It explicitly and directly answers the question. Perhaps you didn't read the question, or the answer.

Comment: @JacekWojcik - I tested it locally before posting my answer. Maybe it varies with the version of macOS? I'm on Yosemite 10.10.5. Also, I released the command key before window-select and ENTER.